# Connect to internet using Huawei E3531

Tags: pi-3, usb, raspbian-stretch, internet

I have Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2 with Raspbian Stretch installed.

I want to connect to internet with my Huawei E3531 dongle.

I already followed this tutorial ([How to use a Huawei E3531 in Modem Mode](https://github.com/EMnify/doc/wiki/How-to-use-a-Huawei-E3531-in-Modem-Mode)) but nothing change I always can't connect to internet

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem/Networkcard
```

ifconfig -a :

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:8a:bc:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:df:e9:74  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wwan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 72:35:18:b6:4d:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3  bytes 270 (270.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

does any one know how to configure this dongle ?

Comment: What tutorial you are following? Did you configure the device on its web interface? https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RU7ECWW2FD7QC/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00HO7CU00

Comment: I followed this one https://github.com/EMnify/doc/wiki/How-to-use-a-Huawei-E3531-in-Modem-Mode

Comment: Again: did you configure the device on its web interface? On which step of the tutorial do you get problems? What's the error message then or difference to the tutorial? Please address me with @Ingo.

Comment: @Ingo No, what web interface you talking about ? and for the tutorial I don't get any error, it's just nothing changes after I did all the steps

Comment: Look at the link I have presented above. Quote: *"It does work, but it requires a little bit of digging around in the web interface of the device."* Seems the dongle has a web interface to configure it.